# MYSQL 5.7 Partition a table based on partition key of another related table

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, partitioning, archive

Please understand a little background before getting to know the problem.

```
TABLE transaction (

t_id: AUTO INCREMENT BIGINT

t_execute_on_date: DATE,

timestamp: DATETIME,

... other columns
)
```

The table `transaction` has 300M (three hundred million) rows and growing (1M rows daily) and growing and we need to drop old data based on the column  `t_execute_on_date`. I plan to drop old data (older than 2 years. approx 40M rows) on the basis of creation monthly range partitions based on KEY `t_execute_on_date`. I have tested this on a test server while using the procedure suggested in @RickJames blog post [PARTITION Maintenance in MySQL](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint):  create a new partitioned table, with optimised indexes according to queries and then reinserting records, and drop old partitions, and this approach seems fine to me. Any suggestions in this approach are also welcome.

I have done this in master-master replication with one master offline, reorganising data, and recovering replication lag, and then drop the old master, bring the traffic to new one, if everything is fine.

```
TABLE transaction_history (

th_id: AUTO INCREMENT BIGINT,

t_id: FOREIGN KEY (t_id of TABLE transaction)

timestamp: DATETIME,

... other columns
)
```

This table has 1.5B+ (One billion five hundred million) rows growing 15M+ daily.
This table has related history of transaction and contains multiple rows corresponding to one `t_id`.

Once old transaction data from table `transaction` is dropped, I would like to drop the same from this table `transaction_history` as well.

This table does not have any key like `t_execute_on_date` based on which I can partition.
This table has 1.5B+ rows I think that adding an additional column `t_execute_on_date` is just not possible.

Like the approach discussed above would I have to manually pull data from table `transaction_history` based on `t_id` of TABLE transaction (reorganised ,old data dropped) and reinserting only the selected records into the new table `transaction_history_partitioned`?

**The PROBLEM I face is how to purge old data from table `transaction_history?`**

Using MYSQL 5.7
Running on
[2.8T HDD, Amazon Linux AMI 2017.03, 16 core, 63GB RAM]

Comment: You say "Amazon"; does that mean RDS?  Or Aurora?  Or neither?

Comment: Have manually installed MySQL 5.7 on a Amazon Linux AMI. It means neither

Comment: Did you consider RDS or Aurora?  They have advantages (and disadvantages).  (I don't have a recommendation.)

Comment: Due to the large size of the Database trying to mitigate migration costs and recurring ones by reducing junk data first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOTE:  `FOREIGN KEYS` are not allowed in partitioned tables.  Simply drop the FKs but keep the indexes that they generated.  Presumably, the FK checks are redundant now that you have debugged your app.

> adding an additional column t_execute_on_date is just not possible.

See `pt-online-schema-change` or `gh-ost`.

Using `PARTITIONs` is the optimal way to delete "old" data from the history table, but there are other approaches:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig

The one that comes to mind is to have a continually-running job that keeps looking at the "next 1000" rows to see if any of them should be deleted.  (It must walk through the table using the `PRIMARY KEY`.)  It might do a `LEFT JOIN` to see which ones are gone, as hinted at in this pseudo-code:

```
$a = 0;
Loop...
    $z = SELECT th_id FROM transaction_history order by th_id LIMIT 1000,1;
    exit loop if $z IS NULL
    SELECT th_id
        FROM      transaction_history AS the
        LEFT JOIN transaction AS t  ON th.t_id = t.t_id
        WHERE t.t_id IS NULL
          AND th.th_id >= $a
          AND th.t_id   < $z
    DELETE those rows -- probably better to do this as a single query
$a = $z;
```

When you exit the Loop, simply start over.

The hope is that this approach to deleting "old stuff" will be fast enough to keep up, though there will be some lag.

Still, I would hope that `pt-online-schema-change` or `gh-ost` can turn a non-partitioned table into a partitioned table with minimal downtime, regardless of table size.  (No FKs.)

Caution:  The optimal indexes for a partitioned table are *usually* different than the equivalent non-partitioned table.  Toss any unused tables when adding partitioning; there is some overhead when building a table with the secondary indexes already in place.

Comment: This loop is good to go for the delete to reduce the size of transaction_history table, but should I consider adding additional key t_execute_on_date (create range partitions on the basis of this key) in the table transaction_history as well for future?

Comment: Once you partition by a date, there probably does not need to be an index _starting_ with that date.  Have only one future partition; use `REORGANIZE PARTITION` just before you need the next month.  See the link that you already found.

Comment: I'm confused -- do you intend to partition both tables?  And drop old data from both of them?

Comment: I'm sorry I would like to explain my first comment; This loop is good to go for the delete to reduce the size of transaction_history table, but should I consider adding additional `COLUMN` t_execute_on_date (create range partitions on the basis of this key) in the table transaction_history as well for future?; Yes once I PARTITION by date, I don't need an index for it since its already in primary key; Yes I intend to partition both tables for the sake of easy `DROP` and `REORGANIZE PARTITION` for dropping old data;

Comment: Sure.  If there is not already a `DATE` (or `DATETIME`) column suitable for `PARTITIONing`, then it should be added.  If the retention period is 2 years, I would probably do monthly partitions.